# use of sample_rate = 1 in randomForest - to fit a single tree

Tags: h2o

I would like to fit a single tree. In the **h2o** R package, I can use `h2o.randomForest()` with the following options:

```
h2o.randomForest(y = y, x = x, training_frame = data, 
                 ntrees = 1, 
                 mtries = number_of_predictors_here,
                 sample_rate = 1)
```

I have a question about `sample_rate` meaning. I assume in case I specify `sample_rate = 1`, it will use all the data. Is this correct? Or it will still do sampling with replacement?

Will this approach provide a correct way to fit a single tree?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is currently the correct way to train a single decision tree in H2O.  We have a [ticket open](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4324) to create a wrapper for this which will make it a bit more straight-forward to use.

If you use `sample_rate = 1`, that means it will not do any sampling, so it will use the full training set.

Another thing to note is that `h2o.randomForest()` has a default `max_depth` value of 20, so if you want the trees to grow all the way down, unconstrained, you might also choose to set that value to something large, like 1000.

Comment: On the other hand, it would be much better if you would provide an API for setting no sampling, rather than using 1 for that purpose. The OP thought in a correct way since even Breiman though about bagging as a sample with replacement of the same size of the original sample.

Comment: Yeah, that's what we have in mind for the future `h2o.decisionTree()` function -- it would be a wrapper for `h2o.randomForest()` that removes any notion of sampling so the user doesn't have to think about or wonder what kind of sampling is going on.

Comment: I must admit I'd not thought about this before, but if sample_rate is 0.9999, is it doing sample-with-replacement? http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/sample_rate.html ought to be explicit about that, one way or the other.

Comment: @DarrenCook Sampling is always without replacement in H2O -- it's just  regular subsampling of the rows.  You're right, we should note that in the docs (will do).